# Mac docker start fatal error: one of the sub-processes failed: com.docker.driver.amd64-linux -addr fd:3 -debug (pid: 1375)

Tags: macos, docker

I don't know why, I just download stable version, and install, and run it, this error was show up, I try 'reset docker to factory defaults' and 're-install', 'reboot my mac', nothing works.

[image]

MAC system: 10.15.7 (19H2)

Answer (score 8):

Hi today I had the same problem, I tried a lot things, but Finally I went to docker site and get an oldest release of the installer.

Docker Desktop Community 2.3.0.3

that works for me.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/

Answer (score 2):

I recently also encountered this issue, but was able to resolve it by **reinstalling the latest version of Docker** (as for this writing, Docker Desktop 3.3.1 (63152)) for macOS.

I know that didn't work for some others, but my two cents is that it would be worth it to try to reinstall the latest version and then install a previous version if the error is still occurring.

Also, there are a couple of other things I tried that didn't work as well, including:

- "Reset Docker to factory defaults" caused a prompt to come up for my password but ended up not resolving the issue.
- Installing `docker` via `brew install docker` and overwriting the existing Docker install seemed to successfully install docker, but not docker desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue and have been forced to go back to older version. 2.3.0.5 worked for me.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2305

Answer (score 0):

Same here on osx 10.13.6. I was running docker 2.3 and when updated to 2.5 it would show that very same error. Downgraded to 2.4 and it works now.